# Colocar o Label do checkbox a esquerda dele

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou tentando colocar o label do checkbox a esquerda dele, mas não estou conseguindo, poderiam me ajudar ?

```html
<label>
    <span>Text goes here</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-2 " checked="checked">
</label>
```

Tente dessa forma, mas mesmo assim não funciona, só funciona quando deixo o *label* abaixo do *input*, mas dessa forma ele coloca o *checkbox* a direita do *label* e no caso preciso a esquerda.

Como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ué pq não tira o **input** de dentro do **label** e coloca o label antes.

Comment: Porque o input não está aparecendo dai

Comment: Matheus, vc quer colocar "Text goes here" do lado esquerdo do checkbox? Isso ja ocorre. Se for do lado direito, basta inverter a linha do span com a do input.  
<label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-2 " checked="checked">
         <span>Text goes here</span>
    </label>

Comment: Sim aqui está acontecendo, mas quando coloco em minha aplicação não está ocorrendo, do lado esquerdo o input não aparece, mas do lado direito ele aparece, é muito estranho.

Comment: Está utilizando frameworks como Bootstrap, Materialize, etc..??

Comment: Estou utilizando Bootstrap @LeAndrade

Comment: Seu código não reproduz o que está descrito no problema, seria importante um [mcve] para poder sanar a dúvida. Clique no link que acabei de passar, que tem umas dicas interessantes de como fazer um exemplo válido.

Answer (score 1):

Está funcionando normal com **Bootstrap 4** creio que com a versão **3** também funcione:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="alert alert-primary">
  <label for="checkbox1">Free</label> 
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-2" id="checkbox1" checked="checked">
</div>

<br>

<div class="alert alert-success">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-2" id="checkbox2" checked="checked">
  <label for="checkbox2">Free</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Fiz os teste com seu exemplo, novamente o input a esquerda funciona, mas o input a direita não está aparecendo vou analisar e ver se encontro algo que possa estar influenciando.